# Mostrar datos de una tabla sql server en php con DataTables

Tags: php, sql-server, datatables

podrían ayudarme con un ejemplo y explicación de como mostrar los datos de una consulta en un DataTable, por el momento me muestra los resultados en una tabla convencional. Tengo el siguiente código:

```
$query="SELECT art_Clave, art_Costo, kar_Fecha, kar_Cantidad, kar_Origen, alma_Existencia, usu_Clave FROM tArticuloKardex WHERE art_Clave='".$buscar."' AND (kar_Fecha BETWEEN '".$formato1."' AND '".$formato2."') ORDER BY kar_Fecha";

        $resultado=sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);
        //se desplegaran los resultados en la tabla
        echo "<table border=1>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>SKU</th>";
        echo "<th>COSTO</th>";
        echo "<th>FECHA DE MOVIMIENTO</th>";
        echo "<th>PIEZAS</th>";
        echo "<th>TICKET</th>";
        echo "<th>EXISTENCIA FINAL</th>";
        echo "<th>USUARIO</th>";
        echo "</tr>";

        while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultado)){
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['art_Clave'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['art_Costo'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.date_format($row['kar_Fecha'], 'd-m-Y').'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['kar_Cantidad'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['kar_Origen'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['alma_Existencia'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['usu_Clave'].'</td>';
            echo '</tr>';           
        }
        echo "</table>";`
```

Comment: a que te refieres con "_mostrar los datos de una consulta en un DataTable_", quieres usar una librería de `JavaScript` si es así te dejo [está](https://datatables.net/). Dale una revisada tal vez te sirva Saludos.

Comment: Exactamente , eso es lo que requiero.

Comment: Veo que has hecho ya varias preguntas en el sitio pero no aceptas las respuestas normalmente ¿ninguna te ha servido/funcionado?

Comment: Si, algunas de ellas me han funcionado. Un ejemplo esta me fue de gran utilidad. Ahora una duda, ¿Como puedo marcar la respuesta?

Comment: Creo que ya viste como marcar la respuesta, ahora puedes hacer un repaso por tus preguntas anteriores y revisar si marcas otras que te hayan sido útiles :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este es el ejemplo básico usando [Datatables.net](https://datatables.net/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
} );
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012/12/02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2012/08/06</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010/10/14</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>2009/09/15</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2008/12/13</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2008/12/19</td>
                <td>$90,560</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                <td>Support Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2013/03/03</td>
                <td>$342,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>2008/10/16</td>
                <td>$470,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2012/12/18</td>
                <td>$313,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>2010/03/17</td>
                <td>$385,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael Silva</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2012/11/27</td>
                <td>$198,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Paul Byrd</td>
                <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2010/06/09</td>
                <td>$725,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gloria Little</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2009/04/10</td>
                <td>$237,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2012/10/13</td>
                <td>$132,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Dai Rios</td>
                <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>2012/09/26</td>
                <td>$217,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
                <td>Development Lead</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2011/09/03</td>
                <td>$345,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Yuri Berry</td>
                <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>2009/06/25</td>
                <td>$675,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Caesar Vance</td>
                <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>2011/12/12</td>
                <td>$106,450</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Doris Wilder</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>Sidney</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2010/09/20</td>
                <td>$85,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/10/09</td>
                <td>$1,200,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>42</td>
                <td>2010/12/22</td>
                <td>$92,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2010/11/14</td>
                <td>$357,650</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
  </table>
```

En tu caso solo agregarías un `id` a tu tabla `echo "<table border=1 id='datatable'>";`. Después de haber cargado las librerías.

- `<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>`
- `<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>`

Y después cargar el `script` para llamar ala librería.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
} );
```

Comment: Los datos son mostrados correctamente de la manera básica pero cuando lo paso para mostrar los datos de mi consulta no funciona el datatable

Comment: tal vez te pueda servir este [apartado](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html)